# Mysql lookup table (Mysql performance issue)

Tags: mysql, sql

I've made a look up table for all my tables. What I'm trying to do is what it is supposed to do, correspond the ID's to the matched values.

I use mysql work bench, server 5.7(newest version doesn't work for me).

I have thousands of values and 6 tables. For a simple explanation lets say I have 3 tables.

```
------------------table1------------------
|   t1ID  |  Person  | Purchase|  Code   |
|    1    |    Jon   |    50   |  111    |    /* Code = t3ID */
|    2    |    Dan   |    100  |  222    |    /* Purchase = Buyer in table2 */
|    3    |    Pete  |    200  |  333    |
          (Many more)

------------------table2------------------
|   t2ID  |  Buyer  | Date   |  Barcode  |
|    1    |    200  | 1/1/20 |   ABC111  |      /* Buyer = Purchase in table1 */
|    2    |    100  | 2/1/20 |   ABC222  |      /* Barcode = Item_ID in table3 */
|    3    |    50   | 3/1/20 |   ABC333  |
               (Many more)

------------------table3---------
|   t3ID  |  Item   | Item_ID   |        /* t3ID =  Code*/
|  111    |  Laser  |  ABC111   |        /* Item_ID = Barcode */
|  222    |  Phones |  ABC222   |   
|  333    |  Tables |  ABC333   |  
               (Many more)

I get this...                                  I need this...
-------------Lookup_Table-------------   -------------Lookup_Table----------           
| lookID  |  t1ID  | t2ID  |  t3ID   |   | lookID  |  t1ID  | t2ID  | t3ID |
|    1    |    1   |    1  |  111    |   |    1    |    1   |    3  |  333 |    
|    2    |    2   |    2  |  222    |   |    2    |    2   |    2  |  222 | 
|    3    |    3   |    3  |  333    |   |    3    |    3   |    1  |  111 |
```

This table is connected by foreign keys and these values were added manually here because the original tables came from CSV files.

My problem is performance or maybe I'm doing it wrong on mysql. When I query by the table ID its works perfectly fine but the values will not match since I added the tableID's afterwards, there are repeated values in certain fields and all the values on the tables are random and they are only connected by those specific values shown above.

When I query select or any other one like `"on table1.Purchase = table2.Buyer"` or `"where"`, to make the comparison and add them to the table properly, the localhost server crashes. It loses connection to mysql server. Also, if its directly compared between the tables, it works but takes over 5 minutes to do that comparison.

If I limit the rows between 0-10000 is fine, above that or if I don't limit it just crashes. I can't limit since I have over 20000 rows, for now.

example is

```
update Lookup_Table lk inner join table1 t1 on t1.t1ID = lk.t1ID
inner join table2 t2 on t2.Buyer = t1.Purchase 
set lk.t2ID = t2.t2ID;
```

Same thing between the other tables. Any idea if I'm doing it wrong or if there's another way of doing this? I've tried so many different things and no luck.

Comment: If the server is outright crashing, you need to get to the bottom of why, that is not normal behaviour. Look at the error log (or syslog, or wherever you have it configured to log errors) and establish what caused the crash. Whay version of MySQL are you using? Have you modified any of the settings from the defaults?

Comment: I use mysql workbench and I'm not sure how to check those logs but I'll look into it. I use mysql server 5.7. When I tried the latest version it wouldn't even accept my csv files and many commands so I couldn't even start my project. Only things I've changed are in the .my file so I can actually load the csv's and a few other things to be able to run it.